# Converting binary file data to floating-point data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I would like to store floating point numbers in a SQL blob record and then read in the data as floating point numbers.  I am not sure this is possible and I have not been able to make the conversion on my own.

For example, suppose I read in the string data `"3f000000"`.  This 4-byte interpreted as an IEEE-754 floating point number would  0.5.
I would like to make this conversion in PHP.  I tried using `$n = floatval(hexdec('3f000000'))` but that just returns an integer number.  Could someone help me with this please?
Also, `$n=floatval('0x3f000000')` just returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that "3f000000" is realy 0.5 ?

it try this :

```
var_dump(unpack("f", pack("H*", "3F000000"))); // give 8.82...E-44
var_dump(unpack("f", pack("H*", "0000003F"))); // give 0.5
```

Comment: I don't understand why "0000003f" gets converted to 0.5 when "3f000000" is the standard IEEE-754 format for 0.5.  But this is a very good start.  Would using unpack be the best way to convert a very large BLOB (Mbs) to floating point numbers?